# How to correctly say "during the whole day" in Ukrainian?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english, різниця-між-словами

There are different variants of "during" translation in this context in Ukrainian, like "упродовж", "протягом", "в перебігу", "на протязі".
Many people confuse correct usage of above variants and I'm one of them.

Comment: Using "на протязі" is actually a widespread mistake. While it sounds almost like "протягом" its meaning is completly different: it is used to talk about being influenced by wind passing through room or building.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to clarify. You [should](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/protyagom-i-na-protyazi) avoid the usage of "на протязі" if you speak about time. It is a common and somewhat annoying mistake. That means the state when both window and door are opened and there is a draft. It lies on the Russian "в течение",  I guess (t be honest, that kind of word combination has a similar common mistake, but we are speaking about Ukrainian).

In your case you can say "протягом" чи "впродовж". The are pretty the same. Sometimes you should use the "during" twice a sentence. To make it sound better you may use both. For example: "Протягом дня я читав чудову книгу, а упродовж ночі не міг заснути". You can say during the whole day I have read the book and during the whole night I couldn't fall asleep (it is better to say just 'at night' maybe, but this is an example).

Answer (score 10):

I believe that the correct variants are "протягом дня" or "упродовж дня", since "протягом" and "упродовж" are considered to be equivalents.
"в перебігу" describes the development or progress of a process

Comment: This answer would benefit from some further explanation and links to credible sources. "I believe" equals to "I have no sources to express my claim", hence, posting an opinionated answer.

Comment: Thanks, have voted up, but going to select another answer, since it contains some references and examples.