# "На протязі року" чи "Протягом року"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, правопис

Як правильно казати "На протязі року" чи "протягом року"?

За словником синонімів слова "на протязі" та "протягом" є синонімами, але мають різні випадки вживання.

Можна отримати білбш детальне пояснення цих слів та приклади їх вживання?

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/169/

Comment: А чому ви не згадали варіант "Впродовж року"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/protyagom-i-na-protyazi)

> Мовознавці радять не плутати:
>
> На протязі – на різкому струмені повітря, що продуває приміщення крізь
>   щілини, отвори, розташовані одне проти одного.
>
> Протягом (упродовж / впродовж) – час існування чогось, тривалості
>   якоїсь дії або процесу.

[image]

[Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53407/31982.html)

> ***ПРОТЯГОМ – НА ПРОТЯЗІ***
>
> Протягом, присл. 1. Вживається при позначенні часу існування когось, чогось, тривання якої-небудь дії, якогось процесу тощо:
>   протягом зими, протягом двох днів, протягом століть, протягом усієї
>   війни, протягом усього життя. 2. розм.
>
> На протязі 1, ім. з прийм. 1. Те саме, що протягом 1.  2. На якійсь відстані. Вздовж всієї стіни на протязі трьох кроків – вартові
>   (С.Божко).
>
> На протязі 2, ім. з прийм. На різкому струмені повітря, що продуває приміщення крізь щілини, отвори, розташовані одне проти
>   одного: стояти на протязі.

[Відео-урок української мови](http://1tv.com.ua/video/2060/load)

Отже, правильно ***"протягом року"***

Comment: Не бачу ніяких доказів подібному твердженню, окрім волюнтаристських забаганок авторів сайту.

Answer (score 3):

В сучасній мові **цілком правильними є обидві конструкції**. Думка про неправомірність конструкції ***на протязі*** не має під собою серйозних підстав.

«Російсько-український словник у трьох томах рекомендує в часовому значенні обидві форми як рівноправні. Однак словоформа на протязі більш властива книжним стилям, зокрема офіційно-діловому». (Культура слова, 1986). 
[Вікіпедія:Список найтиповіших мовних помилок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA#cite_note-8)

**рос. на сквозняке — укр. на протягу.**

- «Це вже вдруге на протязі своєї тринадцятилітньої служби вона мусить через непорозуміння з попом міняти школу», Михайло Коцюбинський
- «Здавалось, він на протязі всього життя не зазнавав такого напрочуд ясного спокою, як зараз», Олесь Гончар

Answer (score -1):

Це не зовсім відповідь на запитання, але в багатьох випадках ще можна казати так:

1. Зовсім без прийменника, наприклад:

   > Приймальна комісія робить [год](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=19011&page=649) (рік).
2. З прийменником *[за](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=27400&page=918)*, наприклад:

   > Інвестор обіцяє побудувати завод за [год](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=19011&page=649) (рік).